# Posting as different users

Tags: customization

I'll try to make this brief.

I am a webmaster for a newspaper and in a single day i am uploading an issue of the paper where there are multiple authors to several articles. Question is: how do i make a post and display a custon author name without having to log into a different user just to get it to display correctly.

I really want to be able to do this all from one admin account.

Thanks folks i really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

On the Edit Post page, click the Screen Options dropdown in the upper right hand corner. Enable the "Author" meta box. Now, on your main edit post page, you'll find the author box, where you can simply select who the author of the post is from a drop down menu.